# Joining 2 fields into another table

Tags: php, mysql

How do i join two fields from table1 to table 2?

I have this code below, how do i also join fields "mobilenumber","firstname" and "lastname" from the user table into the user_address table?

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM user_address WHERE user_id IN 
  (SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = '".$email."')";
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, what are you expecting with *how do i also join fields*?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, think email is on the user table and not the user_address table.

Comment: @NigelRen Yea, now I see the bit I did not see earlier :) Woops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT a.*,b.mobilenumber,b.firstname,b.lastname 
          FROM user_address a 
            left join user b on a.user_id=b.user_id 
          WHERE a.user_id IN 
            (SELECT id FROM user WHERE email = '".$email."')";
```

Comment: The `WHERE a.user_id IN` code is completely redundant as you are already have  the user table in the query - so why do another select?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` instead and select attributes from both table. Example:

```
$query = "SELECT ua.*, 
   u.mobilenumber, 
   u.firstname, 
   u.lastname 
FROM   user_address ua 
   LEFT JOIN USER u 
          ON u.id = ua.user_id 
WHERE u.email = '$email'";
```

Comment: This is missing the select of e-mail address.